# Install package Mvc 6 Beta 2 on VS 2013 Fails via nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently on visual studio 2013 . Now I ran the nuget command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Pre
```

Now the message clearly says

```
 : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, 
contact the package author.
```

Now the package it should install Asp.net Mvc 6.0.0 Beta2 . Now Is that not supported on 2013 yet ? Or should I have to do any extra step. To run it on VS 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Your project uses .NET Framework 4.5, but the MVC 6 needs newer framework(.NET Framework 2015 Preview):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#core

Comment: Thought so . So therez no way to install it currently on 2015 Eh ? without VS2015 ?

Comment: No, vNext requires VS2015. Also, you can't install VS2015 alongside any earlier version of Visual Studio. So, if you want to play around with it, you'll need a virtual machine.

Comment: I would suggest you should try command line option if you just want to play or check only MVC6.

Comment: You can install VS2015 CTP 5 alongside the other versions of VS. I have it running along side 2010, and 2013 with 2015 and 2013 running concurrently.